# Android Studio, NavDrawer and support library issues

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-support-library, greendao

I have a problem using the android support library in my Android Studio project using gradle.
If I add the support-library as dependency I will receive and "Error: Gradle: Execution failed for task ':AppName:dexDebug'.
I have done a some researches and found the problem using the support-library with other dependencies which are using the support libraries as well (greendao 1.3.0).
I would like to use a NavDrawer in my app, so I have to use these support library.
If I remove the support library, of course I will receive an inflate error for the "android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout".

Does somebody here has an idea?

I used two kind of dependency-imports
compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
and
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
cause of a found post in a forum. But that doesn't work, too.

Thanks for your support.

Regards,
Marine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it but I receive the dex error as well.
Attached you could see my current gradle build-file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:1.3.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src-gen/main/java']
        }
    }
}
```

The src-gen folder is used for my greendao generated classes.
Please let me know if you need some more information.

Edit:
I resolved it using the latest greendao version. Added: compile

```
 de.greenrobot:greendao:1.3.1
```

instead of compile

```
 de.greenrobot:greendao:1.3.0
```

Now it works.

Regards,
Marine_of_Hell

Answer (score 1):

If your other dependencies also depend on the support lib, you need to make sure they are not using local dependencies (ie embedding the jar file). You should always use **only**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:x.y.z'
}
```

and not a local dependencies. Make sure all your dependencies do the same and Gradle will automatically detect that everything depends on the same library and only add it once to dex.

Comment: Thanks. I already tested this kind of dependency include but i am not sure anymore if I had a local copy in the lib-folder as well. I will try it later.